# Best practice(s) handling complex UI interations in Angularjs 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface

My apologizes in advance if this question is too general.

The scenario: A form has a series of complex rules governing the  states of various components.

*Arbitrary example*: 
Button 1 is disabled and Input field 1 is required if Button 2 is enabled and Input field 2 has a value of 'x' and Select has a value of 'y'.

Now imagine many instances of the latter example are needed for a given form. For this scneario, let's assume that the behavior of the form cannot be simplified by changing the layout or flow due to client requirements.

Currently, I use a combination of directives (`ngDisable`, `ngRequired`, etc.) and controller scope-defined functions (ex. `ngChange='checkStateOfX()'`) to manage a scneario like above. The aforementioned approach can become unmanageable quickly, in my opinion.

Are there any best practices or angularjs frameworks/plugins for handling such a scenario of complex UI interactions that differ from the approach I am currently using?

Many thanks in advance for your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use controller functions to dictate what manipulated on your UI - use directives. Also, if you're able to, switch to writing components (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component). Doing both of these things will make your life a lot easier. Use of `ngDisable` and `ngIf` will always be useful (and required in some cases).